# unsetting a property using a Ternary Operator

Tags: php, sql, conditional-operator

```
public function checkTheLogin() {

        (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) ? $this->$signedIn = true. $this->userID = $_SESSION['userID'] : $this->signedIn = false. (unset($this->userID));
    }
```

There are 2 properties in my class Session as $signedIn and $userId.So I want to assign $userId to the $_SESSION['userID'] and assign $signedIn = true if there is such session, Else I want to assign $signedIn = false and unset the $userId property.To do this task I decided to use a ternary operator rather than using the if else statement, I have tried it but it throws an error in VS Code.Hope somebody will help thanks.

Comment: Please __do not__ complicate your code. Use `if`. Using ternary will not help in any way here.

Comment: While it is likely possible to achieve this with a ternary operator, when you are executing multiple functions for each condition it is best practice to use a standard if-else statement.

Comment: In some languages you could do this using the comma operator inside the ternary. But PHP doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put multiple expressions in the consequent expressions of the ternary operator. Also, `unset` is a statement, not an expression, so it can't be used inside a ternary at all.

The closest I can come up with is array assignment. But this will set `$this->userID` to `null` rather than unsetting it.

```
[$this->signedIn, $this->userID] = 
    isset($_SESSION['userID']) ? 
        [true, $_SESSION['userID']] : 
        [false, null];
```